# QFT: Lagrangian of a field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, variational-principle, variational-calculus

I just started going through this http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft.html of QFT and I got stuck at the very beginning.
The Lagrangian for the field is derived by:

[image]

I think that the second step in this derivation is integration by parts, however after trying multiple times I still don't get what I need to get. Could someone explain what I'm doing wrong and provide step-by-step derivation?

Comment: Hi @Gytis Vejelis and welcome to PSE. I think your confusion may lay to the fact that $\delta\partial_{\mu}\phi_a= \partial_{\mu}\delta\phi_a$, no? Have you used that?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/252854/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Yes! Now it all makes sense, Thank you!